# how to plot a dataframe with two different axes in pandas matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, group-by, data-visualization, data-analysis

So my data frame is like this:

```
             6month  final-formula  numPatients6month
160243.0       1       0.401193                417
172110.0       2       0.458548                323
157638.0       3       0.369403                268
180306.0       4       0.338761                238
175324.0       5       0.247011                237
170709.0       6       0.328555                218
195762.0       7       0.232895                190
172571.0       8       0.319588                194
172055.0       9       0.415517                145
174609.0      10       0.344697                132
174089.0      11       0.402965                106
196130.0      12       0.375000                 80
```

and I am plotting `6month, final-formula column`

```
  dffinal.plot(kind='bar',x='6month', y='final-formula')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

till now its ok, it shows `6month` in the `x axis` and `final-formula in the y-axis`.
what I want is that to show the `numPatients6month` in the `same plot`, but in another `y axis`.
according to the below diagram. I want to show `numPatients6month` in the position `1`, or simply show that number on `above each bar`.

[image]

I tried to conduct that by twinx, but it seems it is for the case we have two plot and we want to plot it in the same figure.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.set_ylabel('numPatients6month')
```

I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that resolved it.I share here may help someone :)

```
ax=dffinal.plot(kind='bar',x='6month', y='final-formula')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.0))
dffinal.plot(ax=ax2,x='6month', y='numPatients6month')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the `AxesSubplot` in a variable called `ax`

`ax = dffinal.plot(kind='bar',x='6month', y='final-formula')`

and then

`ax.tick_params(labeltop=False, labelright=True)`

This will, bring the labels to the right as well.

Is this enough, or would you like to also know how to add values to the top of the bars? Because your question indicated, one of the two would satisfy.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Actually I do not want to show the same axis in the right. I want Final-formula in the left (as it is now) and add numPatients6month in the right. with your approach it shows the final-formula in both right and left.